# cmake: setting how a specific file is compiled

Tags: c++, cmake

In my [YOMM2 library](https://github.com/jll63/yomm2), I have a file called lab.cpp [(declared in the `CMakeLists.txt` here)](https://github.com/jll63/yomm2/blob/master/tests/CMakeLists.txt#L14), to experiment with new features. Since the library uses complex macro techniques, I would like that specific file to be compiled in two steps:

1. preprocess with -E, sending the output, filtered though clang-format, to an intermediate file
2. compile the intermediate file, producing lab.cpp.o

After quite a bit of googling, I cannot find how to do that. Even worse, while playing with [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/add_custom_command.html), my cmake (v 3.16.3) does not recognize the `OUTPUT` parameter.

Help please?

Comment: `my cmake (v 3.16.3) does not recognize the OUTPUT parameter` Well, then it's two options: your system or cmake is broken and it's like not cmake, or your code is invalid. Please post your code and what have you tried. Because `adD_custom_command` surely has an `OUTPUT` parameter. `Help please?` Please see [ask] and please read [why is "help?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like that specific file to be compiled in two steps:
>
> How to do that

A simple solution would be to add a `add_custom_command` with the preprocessor, then feed the output to the compiler.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test)
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file.c
   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file.c
   COMMAND gcc -E -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file.c ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file.c
)
add_executable(test ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file.c)
```

results in:

```
$ cmake -S. -B_build . && cmake --build _build -v
...
[ 33%] Generating file.c
gcc -E -o /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/file.c /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/file.c
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test.dir/file.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/test.dir/file.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/test.dir/file.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/file.c.o -c /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/file.c
...
```

A great and amazing solution would be to add a custom compiler to CMake that handles your own custom extension in a way you want. That compiler would be just a wrapper around real compiler to do the processing you want.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

I struggled a bit to find how to add the required include directories to your first suggestion. Then, googling some more, I came up with this: https://gist.github.com/jll63/ddc5914abd514f0d38e11c155d615587